# How to use interp1 properly in matlab to find multiple solutions as in parabola?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, ode

I have solved a set of ordinary differential equations to achieve a solution as follows:

```
f = @(t,x) [(-B/m)*x(1);-g-(B/m)*x(2);x(1);x(2)];
[t,x_sol] = ode45(f,[0 5],[V_0*cos(alpha) V_0*sin(alpha) 0 0]);
```

and plotted one of the solutions as follows:

```
plot(t,x_sol(:,4));
```

[image]

All I need to do is to find the time where Y(t) becomes zero. But when I use `t_f = interp1(x_sol(:,4),t,0)` I get the first solution of 0. This might have a simple solution but I cant seem to get the other solution where Y becomes zero (which seems to be something around 4 seconds from the graph). This is actually a trajectory problem and all I simply need to do is to find the trajectory time.

Comment: `interp1` is not meant for this. Use `fzero` instead.

Comment: How could I use fzero in my code? I dont have a function. I have two vectors one "t" and the other "x_sol(:,4)" and I just plot them so far.

Comment: You can always make a set of samples into a function with `fun = @(x) interp1(t,x_sol(:,4),x)`. Note how I use `interp1` as intended there—to interpolate in a sampled function. Your original use, turning the function on its side, yields multiple y values for every x value, which `interp1` doesn’t deal with correctly.